# Cannot select table row id using jquery after ajax update

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, dom

I have a html table containing data rows. I am building add/edit/delete functionality to the table using AJAX.

The format of my table row is as follows:

```
<tr id="281"><td class="todo-task">fdgdg</td><td>some more data</td><td>EDIT BUTTON</td></tr>
```

At the moment I have a working AJAX function to both add a new row and edit a row via a `prepend()`.

In order to edit a table row, you click the edit button which pulls the values into the form and submits ... simples so far. Here's the code for the edit click and the form markup. Note the id from the edit click goes into a hidden field in the form.

```
$("button.edit-todo").bind("click", function(){
var task = $(this).closest('tr').children('td.todo-task').text();
var todoID = $(this).closest('tr').attr("id");

$("div#todo-form input.todo-task").val(task);
$("div#todo-form input.key").val(todoID);
});
```

...

```
<form id="mgnt-edit-todo-form" class="record-edit-form">
 <input type="text" class="todo-task input" name="task">
 <input class="key" name="key" type="hidden" value="279">
 <button class="update uk-button uk-modal-close" type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

... and the ajax bit which binds the hidden field for the update.

```
$("button.update").bind("click", function(e){
var key = $(this).closest('.key').attr('value');
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "update-record.php",
//etc etc etc
```

**The problem**

The first update works fine, it will prepend a table row including the id. The issue occurs when I then wish to make a further update to that same "prepended" row. Whilst the DOM shows the markup as correct the function on `button.edit-todo` will no longer get the id. When looking at the form markup in the DOM, the value of the hidden field is blank.

I've looked at the source in Chrome and I can see that it does not match the view in the browser/DOM. For example, the markup is all the same, but the rows have been put into a different order - it looks as though by date. (There is a date field but I have cut down the fields for this example..) I think this is causing the issue ... question is why? and how do i fix it?

Thanks

**Update**

Here is my markup in the DOM, looks fine to me.

[image: My markup]

To be absolutely clear the issue is occuring when clicking the edit button.

It calls the following function (now using 'on':

```
$("button.edit-todo").on("click", function(){
//load the data from this row
var task = $(this).closest('tr').children('td.todo-task').text();
var client = $(this).closest('tr').children('td.todo-client').text();
var due = $(this).closest('tr').children('td.todo-due').text();
var todoid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');

$("div#todo-form input.todo-task").val(task);
$("div#todo-form select").val(client);
$("div#todo-form input.todo-due").val(due);
$("div#todo-form input.key").val(todoid);
});
```

Clicking row 286 works as intended (it was present on the page load) in that the tr id is added to the hidden field in the form. Clicking row 297 (as far as I'm aware in the DOM?) does not pass the id to the hidden field...

Please help!!! Doing my head in...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `.bind` use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$("button.edit-todo").on("click", function(){
(...)
```

and

```
$("button.update").on("click", function(e){
(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using ID for loaded data is not very comfortable way anymore. Use class instead of ID.

Also jQuery has changed "bind" to "on" method. I recommend to use "on".

For example:

```
$(document).on("click", ".edit-todo", function(){
   var task = $(this).closest('tr').children('.todo-task').text();
   var todoID = $(this).closest('tr').attr("id");

   $(".todo-form .todo-task").val(task);
   $(".todo-form .key").val(todoID);
});
```

Also, source shows the code when the document loads, not the dynamic DOM.

Comment: When I add a new row via AJAX the source is definitely changing... (in chrome anyway!) For example, a row on the screen/DOM will be prepended to the beginning of the table as desired, but in the source it seems to be getting placed in the 'correct' row if it were to be sorted by date...? I haven't refreshed the page..!

Comment: Thanks nika your suggestion of using 'on' did work I just didn't implement it correctly first time around. Thanks.